# Better way to parse the file?

Tags: java, file, filereader

I have a sample data of employees.

```
Brad Senior
<Fname>Brad Junior</Fname>
    CHICAGO, March 6 1990 - He is a great Java Developer.
He has worked in XYZ company.
```

Data is in the format:

```
Person's name
<Fname> xxx </Fname>   // Optional
   Current Location, DOB - Description about his work.
```

I am able to parse it using BufferedReader and by using so many conditions.

Is there a better way to pares this content (e.g. Regex) and store it in a Employee object?

I cannot use external libraries.

Thanks.

Comment: If the data is in XML, use an XML parser...seriously, SO much eaiser

Comment: Is the data in actual XML, or is this the exact data format?

Comment: If it's a standard format, use a parser for that (i.e. XML or something). Regular expressions only work for regular languages (i.e. if you have a nested tag like `<Fname>` it won't work). In that case tokenizing is the best.

Comment: Data is not in XML format. It is as per the format given.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a parser generator as [Cup](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/).

It's really useful when the format becomes more complex. It also makes maintenance of the parser easier if the file format is extended.

Answer (score 0):

Better is an opinion so your question is innately unanswerable. As Tobías stated parsers are arguable and your options are vast. I recommend the industry standard [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) in  opposition to [Cup](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/) due to the fact that it has absolutely no license information anywhere I could find.

Comment: At the following link you can find cup's license: 
http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/install.php

Comment: Thanks, I was looking in all the wrong places apparently.

Comment: I cannot use external libraries. Can you provide other way?

Comment: Easiest solution with that restriction is unfortunately Regex; though if you need speed a custom logic will always beat any outside library as it is uniquely attributed to the situation. Also, switch to NIO, the file operations can be non-blocking and ridiculously quicker than the "iostream.h" wrapper that is "java.io". Ideal design would be the "Factory" complex, where data is provided to a static instantiater for production of Employee objects. I know this isn't the answer you were hoping for, you have my condolences.